# How do I target a div on a specific WordPress page using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to remove the margin-left on http://insightcxo.com/epicwin/

The problem is when I target the class `.container`, it shifts the whole website over - I only want to target the div on the specific page.

This is the code I'm using that makes the page work but shifts the whole website over as well:

```
.container {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I just checked it, your `margin-left: 0;` works as intended, it did not shift the whole website for me. This worked for me because The code was inline, and not conflicting with the default bootstrap container class

Comment: So, you want the margin on the left side of the header and navigation, but not on the .container in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most WordPress themes (including yours) include the page ID as a `body` class name. In this case, the `<body>` tag looks like the following:

```
<body class="page page-id-731 page-template-default page-shadow responsive-fluid ">
```

This means that you can target this page via:

```
.page-id-731 .container {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

More about WordPress's `body_class()` function can be found [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class).

Answer (score 2):

As per the page you are linking, it seems you are using an page-id as a class in your body, so this might work:

```
.page-id-731 .container {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again taxicala!

I'd give you the check mark but mevis beat you too it! I'm sure I'll have more questions you can answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand completely, but I think what you need to do is add an id to the div you want to target.

Here is a JSFiddle of what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/dT9Yk/25/

HTML:

```
<div class="div1"></div><br>
<div class="div1" id="marginleft"></div><br>
<div class="div1"></div><br>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: red;
}

#marginleft{
margin-left:10%;
}
```

As you can see they all have the same class name but the middle one has an additional id tag.

Comment: Thanks for your help Blezx! mevius was the first to answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the body on that page only and then use specificity to target the container on only that page. For instance, add body class `epicwin` on that page and then use

```
.epicwin .container {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

to target it.

Comment: Thanks for your help APAD1! mevius was the first to answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin-left: 0px;` to your CSS file is conflicting with the default `.container` class of bootstrap.
To fix your issue apply the class directly inline, it will solve your issue, like so:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-left: 0px;">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ahs N! mevius was the first to answer though.

Comment: @ahh_wang I don't mind, as long as your issue has been solved, all is good :D

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create something like this in the stylesheet you are using:

   `.Container_Div { padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}`
2. Add this to your HTML:

   `div class="Container_Div"`

Try this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can target a div with class/id .you can target directly or with reference of parents div class/id as follow.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

direct target

```
.child{}
```

with reference to parent div .It will only apply style to class/id that exist in parent with specific id/class

```
.parent .class{
}
```